# C++ Help: Finding words in text with arrays and loops

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

Accept some text from the user. Accept the string that needs to be searched. Your program is supposed to print the number of occurrences of the string found within the text, and the position at which the pattern was found. Look at the following sample output:

for my function

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, I need help!

```
void getText()
{
    string itext, word;
    int position;
    bool done =  false;
    cout << "Enter some text" << endl;
    cin >> itext;
    cout << "Enter the word or phrase to wish to find" << endl;
    cin >> word;
    char text[itext.length()];
    char search[word.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i < itext.length(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++)
        {
            if(text[i] = search[j])
            {
                position = i;
                cout << position;
            }
        } 
    }
```

}

Comment: ok, what's the problem? We aren't doing your homework for you. Outline what you're having trouble with so we can help

Comment: I have no idea what I'm doing wrong

Comment: well explain what you **think** you are doing right. Give us your thought process behind what you wrote and what output you are receiving, if any. Be specific, no one is going to waste their time on your question if you aren't clear

Comment: Accept some text from the user. Accept the string that needs to be searched. Your program is supposed to print the number of occurrences of the string found within the text, and the position at which the pattern was found. Look at the following sample output:

Comment: Everything was going so well up to the point where you declared a `char` array. This can, and should, all be done using `string`. (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

Comment: my professor said to use char omg

Comment: Get rid of the arrays with random content.  You can use `[]` on a `string`, line `itext[i]`.  The result is a `char`, so that meets your professor's requirement.

Answer (score 0):

First text and search aren't initialized to itext and word .
Second your if should be == and not = .
Third your checking method is wrong , thats something you need to figure out (U need to do your homework).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't create array with dynamic length.

Second we use `==` in `if` statements when comparing two values.

Finally Here I recode your solution using `string.find("searchPhrase", startIndex)`. hope help you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void getText()
{
    string itext, word;
    int position;
    bool done =  false;
    cout << "Enter some text" << endl;
    cin >> itext;
    cout << "Enter the word or phrase to wish to find" << endl;
    cin >> word;

    int startIndex = 0 ;
    while( itext.find(word,startIndex) != -1)
    {
        cout<<"Found at "<<itext.find(word,startIndex)<<endl;
        startIndex = itext.find(word,startIndex) + 1; // we update start point of next seatch
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you some directions for an option to solve it basing your code.

The char arrays was removed. because was not initialized and was not needed.

inner loop should be over an only then you can tell if word have been found.

to read whole sentence you'll need to use getline.

compare is by using `==` not just `=`. I preferred `!=` which mean not equal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     string text, word;

    int position;
    bool done =  false;

    cout << "Enter some text" << endl;

    getline(cin, text); //if you want line with white spaces...

    cout << "Enter the word or phrase to wish to find" << endl;
    cin >> word;

    size_t i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < word.length(); j++)
        {
            if(text[i+j] != word[j])
            {
                break;//inner for
            }
        } 
        if(j == word.length()){ //means inner loop run till the end.
            position = i;
            cout << position<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter some text
abcd abc abcd
Enter the word or phrase to wish to find
abc
0
5
9
```

Comment: yes, I had problem with the source.

Comment: This stuff still doesn't work out, I'm about to give up and accept a poor grade on this.

Comment: It completed solution now with run example. just copy the code and you can run it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to do your HW for you, but I'll give some pointers that should help you get there.

```
char text[itext.length()];
char search[word.length()];
```

This makes no sense. I'm not even sure if it's legal, but if it is, it's still a bad idea because you wouldn't have room for your null terminator. Furthermore, you already have the values stored in `itext` and `word`, so why would you put them somewhere else?

`string` has a find method ([string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)) Try using that the find the instance starting from zero, then search again at the position found + 1. Repeat until the search fails.